# Как вывести на экран значение объекта, используемого интерфейсом Map?

Tags: java

Проблема в том, что не знаю как вывести какой либо объект типа ua.edu.kep.LR_7.StudentInfo. Например, как вывисти на экран максимальный балл всех студентов с карты studentsInfo?

Класс StudentsMap:

```
    package ua.edu.kep.LR_7;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;

    public class StudentsMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, StudentInfo> studentsInfo = new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();
    StudentInfo info = new StudentInfo();

    info.setMinimal((float) 7);
    info.setAverage((float) 8.4);
    info.setMaximal((float) 10);
    studentsInfo.put("Вася Пупкін", info);

    info.setMinimal((float) 9);
    info.setAverage((float) 10.1);
    info.setMaximal((float) 11);
    studentsInfo.put("Нехлюй Петро", info);

    info.setMinimal((float) 6);
    info.setAverage((float) 8.6);
    info.setMaximal((float) 10);
    studentsInfo.put("Придорожний Семен", info);

    }

    }
```

Класс StudentInfo:

```
package ua.edu.kep.LR_7;

public class StudentInfo {
private float minimal;  
private float average; 
private float maximal;  

public float getMinimal(){
    return minimal;
}

public void setMinimal( float value ){
    minimal = value;
}

public float getAverage(){
    return average;
}

public void setAverage( float value ){
    average = value;
}

public float getMaximal(){
    return maximal;
}

public void setMaximal( float value ){
    maximal = value;
}

}
```

Comment: Поконкретнее. Что именно нужно вывести?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первый у тебя ошибка при добавлении в `Map`. Ты всегда используешь `info`. В результате, ты его переиспользуешь, вместо того, чтобы реально создать три разных объекта `StudentInfo`. В итоге у тебя в `info` всегда будут данные только последние что ты добавил. и получится, что  все три студента у тебя имеют значения:

```
6.0
8.6
10.0
```

чтобы этого не было, надо создавать отдельные объекты для каждого студента. Например, если данные устанавливаются при инициализации (хотя по методам setMinimal/setAverage/setMaximal это и не скажешь), то достаточно объявить конструктор, в который передать параметры инициализации:

```
public StudentInfo(float min,float avg, float max){
    minimal = min;
    average = avg;
    maximal = max;
}
```

И тогда данные будут заполняться так:

```
Map<String, StudentInfo> studentsInfo = new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();

studentsInfo.put("Вася Пупкін", new StudentInfo(7f, 8.4f, 10f));
studentsInfo.put("Нехлюй Петро", new StudentInfo(9f, 10.1f, 11f));
studentsInfo.put("Придорожний Семен", new StudentInfo(6f, 8.6f, 10f));
```

---

Чтобы вывести максимальный балл каждого студента, нужно просто организовать цикл по `Map` и вывести соответствующие данные с помощью методов `get`

```
System.out.println("Максимальный бал студентов: ");

for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> entry : studentsInfo.entrySet()) {
    StudentInfo studentInfo = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + studentInfo.getMaximal());
}
```

---

Если имелось в виду вывести вообще студентов с максимальным баллом, то для этого нужно

- Найти какой у всех студентов балл максимальный
- Выбрать по этому признаку студентов.

Пример со стримами Java8:

```
public static Map<String, StudentInfo> getStudentWithMax(Map<String, StudentInfo> students){
    float maxItem = students.entrySet().stream().map(el -> el.getValue().getMaximal()).max(Float::compareTo).get();
    Map<String, StudentInfo> result = students.entrySet().stream().filter(num -> num.getValue().getMaximal() == maxItem).collect(Collectors.toMap(
            e -> e.getKey(),
            e -> e.getValue()
    ));

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, StudentInfo> students = new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();

    students.put("Вася Пупкін", new StudentInfo(7f, 8.4f, 10f));
    students.put("Нехлюй Петро", new StudentInfo(9f, 10.1f, 11f));
    students.put("Придорожний Семен", new StudentInfo(6f, 8.6f, 11f));

    System.out.println("Студенты с максимальным баллом: ");
    Map<String, StudentInfo> studentWithMax = getStudentWithMax(students);
    for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> stringStudentInfoEntry : studentWithMax.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(stringStudentInfoEntry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Пример без стримов Java8

```
public static Map<String, StudentInfo> getStudentWithMax2(Map<String, StudentInfo> students){
    float max = 0f;
    Map<String, StudentInfo> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> entry : students.entrySet()) {
        StudentInfo studentInfo = entry.getValue();
        if (studentInfo.getMaximal() == max)
            result.put(entry.getKey(), studentInfo);

        if (studentInfo.getMaximal() > max) {
            max = studentInfo.getMaximal();
            result.clear();
            result.put(entry.getKey(), studentInfo);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, StudentInfo> students = new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();

    students.put("Вася Пупкін", new StudentInfo(7f, 8.4f, 10f));
    students.put("Нехлюй Петро", new StudentInfo(9f, 10.1f, 11f));
    students.put("Придорожний Семен", new StudentInfo(6f, 8.6f, 11f));

    System.out.println("Студенты с максимальным баллом: ");
    Map<String, StudentInfo> studentWithMax = getStudentWithMax2(students);
    for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> stringStudentInfoEntry : studentWithMax.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(stringStudentInfoEntry.getKey());
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей, все работает! Два последних примера не потребовалось. Вы все правильно поняли с самого начала. Но я столкнулся с другой прблемой. Как вывести все балы (max, min, average) всех студентов? Или это уже другой вопрос и другая тема для разговора?

Comment: @Владимир что значит все баллы? и минимальный и средний и максимальный? Всё абсолютно также, как и с максимумом. Только вместо `getMaximal()` будет к примеру `System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + "max - " + studentInfo.getMaximal() + ", min - "+ studentInfo.getMinimal() + ", avg - " + studentInfo.getAverage());` ......... в каком виде выводить - решать тебе..... данные же уже доступны через `get` - просто бери

Comment: Спсибо, я уже и сам догадался) Это очень просто!

Comment: Можно последний вопрос? Если нужно вывести на экран список имен студентов, у которых равны минимальные баллы или средние баллы или максимальные баллы, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Владимир это уже скорее можно оформить другим вопросом, но будет в таком же стиле, что и я написал выборку студентов с максимальным значением. То есть через дополнительные выборки и фильтры в виде `students.entrySet().stream().filter(....` и т.д. ........... кстати, не вижу смысла делать  `Map<String, StudentInfo>`. Скорее надо создавать новый класс `Students` в котом будет хранится его имя а также  его инфа по оценкам в виде полей, либо в виде переменной с типом `StudentInfo`. И в итоге делать список со студентами...Ибо мапа никак не идентифицирует студентов. имхо - лучший вариант

Comment: @Владимир вообще советую все свои шаги по задаче просто для начала на листчоке записывать. нужно найти студентов у кого равны максимальные баллы? нарисуй на листочке как это должно выглядеть. Потом подбери тип в java, который будет похож на то, что ты написал на листочке. Потом прикинь что тебе для этого нужно. Сравнивать каждого студента с каждым другим? значит нужно перебрать в цикле список чтоб пробежаться по всем, и второй цикл, чтоб сравнить с каждым остальным. и т.д. Может в итоге алгоритм и код выйдет большим - зато наглядным

Comment: Хорошо. Так и зделаю. Сначала попробую сам. А в итоге если не выйдет, приду сюда. Спасибо за ваши советы!

Comment: Если вам будет интересно посмотреть мое решение этой последней проблемы оставляю ссылку (хотя это скорее всего только попытка решения): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671532/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83