# Реализует ли программа поставленную задачу?

Tags: java, map

Вот следующая задача:

Вывести на экран список имен студентов, у которых равны минимальные баллы или средние баллы или максимальные баллы.

Программа написана, но я сумниваюсь правильно ли я написал ее. Если можете прокоментировать, ответьте, пожалуйста, на вопрос: реализует ли программа поставленную выше задачу? Возможно есть какие-то ошибки. Возможно, если ее можно написать проще, или лучше с вашей точке зрения, как это должно выглядеть?

Класс StudentsMap:

```
package ua.edu.kep.LR_7;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StudentsMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, StudentInfo> studentsInfo = new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();

    studentsInfo.put("Вася Пупкін", new StudentInfo(7f, 8.4f, 11f));
    studentsInfo.put("Нехлюй Петро", new StudentInfo(9f, 10.1f, 10f));
    studentsInfo.put("Придорожний Семен", new StudentInfo(6f, 8.6f, 11f));

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    int k = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> entry : studentsInfo.entrySet()) {
        StudentInfo studentInfo = entry.getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> entry2 : studentsInfo.entrySet()) {
            StudentInfo studentInfo2 = entry2.getValue();
            if ( studentInfo.getAverage() == studentInfo2.getAverage() 
                    && studentInfo.getMaximal() == studentInfo2.getMaximal()
                    && studentInfo.getMinimal() == studentInfo2.getMinimal()) {
                k++;
                if (k <= 1)
                    System.out.println("Null");
                else System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " +
                        "Середнє = " + studentInfo.getAverage() +
                        ", Max = " + studentInfo.getMaximal() +
                        ", Min = " + studentInfo.getMinimal());
            }
            else System.out.println("Null");
        }
    }

}

}
```

**EDIT.** Класс StudentsMap:

```
package ua.edu.kep.LR_7;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StudentsMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, StudentInfo> studentsInfo = new HashMap<String, StudentInfo>();

    studentsInfo.put("Вася Пупкін", new StudentInfo(7f, 8.4f, 11f));
    studentsInfo.put("Нехлюй Петро", new StudentInfo(9f, 10.1f, 10f));
    studentsInfo.put("Придорожний Семен", new StudentInfo(6f, 8.6f, 11f));

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> entry : studentsInfo.entrySet()) 
    {
        StudentInfo studentInfo = entry.getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<String, StudentInfo> entry2 : studentsInfo.entrySet()) 
        {
            StudentInfo studentInfo2 = entry2.getValue();
            if ( entry.getKey() != entry2.getKey() && (studentInfo.getAverage() == studentInfo2.getAverage() 
                    || studentInfo.getMaximal() == studentInfo2.getMaximal()
                    || studentInfo.getMinimal() == studentInfo2.getMinimal()) ) 
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " +
                    "Середнє = " + studentInfo.getAverage() +
                    ", Max = " + studentInfo.getMaximal() +
                    ", Min = " + studentInfo.getMinimal());
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Класс StudentInfo:

```
package ua.edu.kep.LR_7;

public class StudentInfo {
private float minimal;  
private float average; 
private float maximal;  

public StudentInfo(float min,float avg, float max){
    minimal = min;
    average = avg;
    maximal = max;
}

public float getMinimal(){
    return minimal;
}

public void setMinimal( float value ){
    minimal = value;
}

public float getAverage(){
    return average;
}

public void setAverage( float value ){
    average = value;
}

public float getMaximal(){
    return maximal;
}

public void setMaximal( float value ){
    maximal = value;
}

}
```

Результат:
[image: Скриншот результата выполнения программы]
**EDIT.** Новые результаты:

*Если есть равные значения в коде*
[image: Если есть равные значения в коде]
Нету равных значений в коде
[image: Если нет в коде равних значений]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не-а, неправильно.

Для начала, у вас в условии нужны студенты, у которых «равны минимальные баллы **или** средние баллы **или** максимальные баллы.»

А у вас в коде написано

```
if ( studentInfo.getAverage() == studentInfo2.getAverage() 
  && studentInfo.getMaximal() == studentInfo2.getMaximal()
  && studentInfo.getMinimal() == studentInfo2.getMinimal())
```

что уж никак не «или».

Затем, ваша логика с `k` совершенно неверна. Вы, судя по всему, хотели, чтобы один и тот же студент не учитывался при сравнении с самим собой. Но первым встреченным студентом может быть и другой студент с теми же оценками. Поэтому не пытайтесь смухлевать и просто проверяйте студентов на одинаковость (подумайте, как именно).

Затем, вы выводите `Null`, который вовсе не требовался в условии. Уберите его.

---

Для старшекурсников: вы избрали не самый оптимальный путь. Вы перебираете вашу структуру данных на каждой итерации потому, что ваша структура данных умеет эффективно ответить на вопрос «какие оценки у студента с данным именем?», но не на вопрос «какие студенты имеют данный средний балл?». Возможно, имеет смысл построить индексы (`HashMap`), отображающие балл в набор студентов, имеющих этот балл. Построение индексов будет `O(n)`, и проверка после этого тоже станет `O(n)`.

Но это уже продвинутый вариант, и потребует полного переписывания вашего кода.

Comment: Ех, думал прокатит :)

Comment: @Владимир: Ну зависит от препода, конечно :)

Comment: Влад, смог исправить некоторые ошибки! Реально работает!

Comment: @Владимир: Отлично! Рад, что помогло!